# BackboneJS Jquery How to pass values to magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

How can I pass values which I get from a click event in Backbone to my `Magnific popup`?

So far, my View looks like this:

```
events: {
   'click .albumolfull': 'listenAlbum'
},

listenAlbum: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var album = $(e.currentTarget).find('a');
    this.openMusicService(album);
},

openMusicService: function(album){
   $.magnificPopup.open({
       items: {
           src: '#pickservice', 
       },
       type: 'inline',
       disableOn: 700,
       mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
       removalDelay: 160,
       preloader: false,
       fixedContentPos: false,
   });
}
```

And my HTML looks like this (I use HandlebarsJS):

```
<div class="albumolfull">
    <span>PLAY</span>
    <div style="display:none;">
    {{#each services}}
        <a href="{{id}}" target="blank">{{name}}</a>
    {{/each}}
    </div>                              
</div>
```

and the HTML for the popup (in same template):

```
<div id="pickservice" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
    <section class="ppw-links ip">
       <div id="ppwlinkh">
           <h2>Vælg tjeneste:</h2>
       </div>
        <div class="ipof">
           <ol class="olls">
            {{#each releases}}
                {{#each services}}
                    <li class="ls2">
                        <a href="{{id}}"><button class="btnspotify">&nbsp;</button>{{name}}</a>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
            {{/each}}
          </ol>
        </div>
    </section>
 </div>
```

the values `id` and `name` gets provided by an API as JSON.

How can I achieve this? please help...

Comment: this.openMusicService(album, e) ?

Comment: @Evgeniy Hi again! :-) no, unfortunately not

Comment: Hi) what would you like to pass to popup? as i can see you call openMusicService on every click and openMusicService open popup, correct?

Comment: yeah, lets say I have 5 music albums who serve different music service ids, when user clicks on one of the albums, the magnific popup should display the relevant music service links

Comment: Could you not set a data attribute on the HTML with the id and name then in your click method you could access them like: $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id'); and or $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-name'); You could then store the details and pass them through to the popup? You should be able to access them as it currently stands with $(e.currentTarget).html() for name and $(e.currentTarget).attr('href'); for id

Comment: then you have to use as dynamic element like -  src: $('<div>Dynamically created element</div>') .This element you can create as compiled handlebar template or rendered BB view. var popupView = new popUpview({ id : 123}) Like src:popupView.render().$el.html()

Comment: @Ryank Didn't work - somehow it must be the `magnific popup`. Doesnt matter which album I click, in the popup it displays all links from all albums, not the specific one

Comment: @Evgeniy "This element you can create as compiled handlebar template" - didnt understand that

Comment: @SHT The best thing would be to move the popup into another view then the method I mentioned would work as you could open a popup with the specific information. Alternatively in the click function you could set the values with jQuery to be in the popup and render out what you need. I would recommend using a view for the popup also.

Comment: @SHT, sorry , forget adout it, just use second approach